# filter a column to show only two values

Tags: mysql

I have a baseball dataset and for the column `teamid` I would like to retrieve only 2 teams.

This is my code:

```
SELECT teamID, yearID, salary
FROM   Salaries 
WHERE  s.teamID LIKE '%HOU%' AND  '%TEX%'
GROUP BY yearID
ORDER BY yearID ASC;
```

My code only shows me the TEX results.

DATA: [Salaries Table](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1af03df5227cda307999744dee13faaa)

Expected result

| teamID | yearID | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HOU | 2013 | 100 |
| TEX | 2015 | 300 |

Comment: Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 with data that illustrates the problem, update your post with the URL and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your query. First, (teamID, salary) is likely not functionally dependent of yearID so you can't group by yearID alone. In this case you probably don't need a group by clause at all. Second, WHERE  s.teamID LIKE '%HOU%' AND  '%TEX%' is probably not evaluated the way you expect. I suspect you want:

```
WHERE  s.teamID LIKE '%HOU%' OR s.teamID LIKE '%TEX%'
```

Note that you need the LIKE predicate twice and a logical operator (OR) to combine the result.

```
SELECT teamID, yearID, salary
FROM   salaries s
WHERE  s.teamID LIKE '%HOU%' OR s.teamID LIKE '%TEX%'
ORDER BY yearID ASC;

teamID  yearID  salary  s.teamID LIKE '%HOU%'   s.teamID LIKE '%TEX%'
HOU 2013    100 1   0
TEX 2015    300 0   1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11dcc1d248d77e6b302b67161caa894d)

Comment: Amazing! thank you Lennart!